# What does a shared host provider need to do to be Django-friendly?

Tags: django, shared-hosting

I've purchased an account with a shared hosting provider.

Unfortunately, they are not even aware of Django and can't help me on with it at all (I should have asked more before whether they know this...).

But, they have the willingness to help me, and now they ask me what they can do on their side to make it possible to install and run django.

What they already provide:

- access to the compiler: I could use gcc.
- SSH access
- Virtual environment

What I've already managed to do thanks to that:

- Installing Python 3.4 (the shared hosting runs Python 2.6.6 by default)
- Installing Django 1.8 in the Python 3.4 virtual environment.

So, what are the next steps for them? What should I ask for?

Comment: What kind of webserver do they run? Do you have access to configure it?

Comment: `uname -a` on ssh gives me: `Linux (name of my provider) 2.6.32-604.30.3.lve1.3.63.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 27 06:34:10 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Is it helpful?

Comment: Skip the headache, get a refund and open an account at WebFaction. You'll have your site running in about 15 minutes tops.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What web serving software is there?

Comment: Sorry. I had the answer: they run nginx + Apache. Thanks a lot for your help!